# Filling DataGridView with list that contains another list to populate a Comboboxcolumn. VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, list, datagridview

I'm having trouble to fill a Datagrid with a list, that contains another two.

The code I'm using for the list is:

```
Public Class RegistroComanda

    Private _IdPedido As Integer
    Public Property IdPedido() As Integer
        Get
            Return _IdPedido
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _IdPedido = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _id_Plato As Integer
    Public Property id_Plato() As Integer
        Get
            Return _id_Plato
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _id_Plato = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _receta As String
    Public Property Receta() As String
        Get
            Return _receta
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _receta = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _comentarios As String
    Public Property comentarios() As String
        Get
            Return _comentarios
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _comentarios = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _estados As List(Of EstadoBE)
    Public Property Estados() As List(Of EstadoBE)
        Get
            Return _estados
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As List(Of EstadoBE))
            _estados = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _Usuarios As List(Of UsuarioBE)
    Public Property usuarios() As List(Of UsuarioBE)
        Get
            Return _Usuarios
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As List(Of UsuarioBE))
            _Usuarios = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

What i need to fill with this list is a DatagridView that contains 4 DataGridTextBoxColumn for the first 4 Attributes (id_pedido, id_plato, receta, descripcion), and with the two list of objects remaining(Estados and Usuarios) i need to populate a DataGridComboBox with each (Each one contains a description that i need to show).

Here's the catch: each list inside the RegistroComanda List can contain different amount of objects. For example: If i have two records of RegistroComanda, the first one can contain 5 objects in the "Usuario" list, and the second one can contain only 2.

In that case, what i need to show when i display the combobox for the first row, are the list of 5 users, and when i display the combo for the second row i need to see only the two that corresponds to that RegistroComanda.

I've tried to set the datasource of the grid = List Of RegistroComanda, but that doesnt seem to work.

Any thougts on how i can work with this??

Thanks.

Comment: My first Thought is that you should read [ask] and take the [tour].  Each Combo column would have its own DataSource.  Typically each column would be constrained to some set of values as opposed to a free form list.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Im running out of time with this issue, so that's why i couldnt take the tour, an ended with a sloppy post. Im willing to do it ASAP.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you need to base the contents of one combobox on the selection of another in the same row. This is a bit challenging because all comboboxes in a column must have the same data source. However, you can filter the datasource on the EditingControlShowing event so it appears that the data is changed. I can't remember the details but I wrote it up in an old msdn forum answer a million years ago. You might be able to find it under user "molku".

Comment: You understooded correctly. Im gonna check on the msdn forums for what you told me. Thanks a lot